# How to hide out-of-range locations for LinkedIn news feed "jobs I may be interested in"?

Tags: linkedin, news-feed

I am a frequent user of LinkedIn, especially the news feed. The news feed includes activity updates from my network of contacts as well as LinkedIn suggestions about **jobs** I may be interested in.  For instance, in the news feed, I see stories of the format:

> **FrobozzCo International**  posted a job you may be interested in: *Senior Magic Widget
>   Developer* in *The Great Underground Empire, Zork Universe*.

If the location is too far away, I don't want to see such jobs cluttering my news feed. Is there a way to hide out-of-range job locations from LinkedIn's *"jobs I may be interested in"* suggestion generator?

Specifically, I need to know the preference setting for *"Don't show me jobs that aren't within __ km of ______"?*

Clarification: These recommendations are for jobs at companies I am *not* following on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 2):

You can click the "See More" link at the bottom of the Jobs pane which opens up a new page with an expanded list. On that page you can use the faceted filter boxes at the left to narrow the listings. Unfortunately, however, there is no way to permanently save your preferences in this regard.

Note that the "Jobs you may be interested in" feature is still in Beta, and they are actively soliciting feedback (see the link at the bottom of the page), so I recommend clicking that link and making this suggestion.

Comment: Clarification: The "Feedback" link is right at the bottom of the "Jobs You May Be Interested In" sidebox.